# Android firebase method chaining with conditions

Tags: java, android, function, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know this is a silly question but I need to know if I am doing this right. I am using firebase firestore database to store data of properties which is sorted and filters in my Android app. The user can filter those properties according to areas i.e. if he selects a specific area then properties of those areas only will be listed and if he chooses 'all' then all properties will be listed. I am achieving this logic via the following code:-

```
private void updateListViewOldest(String city, String area, Long type) {
   final ArrayList<PropertyListObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    if (area.equals("All")) {
        db.collection("Properties")
                .orderBy("postTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .whereEqualTo("city", city)
                .whereEqualTo("type", type)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                propertyListPosition.add(document.getId());
                                PropertyFetchObject pfo = document.toObject(PropertyFetchObject.class);

                                objects.add(new PropertyListObject(pfo.getPrice(), pfo.getName(), pfo.getArea(), pfo.getSize(), getTime(pfo.getPostTime()), pfo.getCity()));
                            }

                            PropertiesListAdapter propertyAdapter = new PropertiesListAdapter(PropertyAds.this, objects);
                            adsListView.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(PropertyAds.this, "error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        db.collection("Properties")
                .orderBy("postTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .whereEqualTo("city", city)
                .whereEqualTo("type", type)
                .whereEqualTo("area", area) // just added this
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                propertyListPosition.add(document.getId());
                                PropertyFetchObject pfo = document.toObject(PropertyFetchObject.class);

                                objects.add(new PropertyListObject(pfo.getPrice(), pfo.getName(), pfo.getArea(), pfo.getSize(), getTime(pfo.getPostTime()), pfo.getCity()));
                            }

                            PropertiesListAdapter propertyAdapter = new PropertiesListAdapter(PropertyAds.this, objects);
                            adsListView.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(PropertyAds.this, "error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Is writing whole code again just for the line

> .whereEqualTo("area", area)

is right? Or there is a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code could be a lot simpler if you separate the building of the query from the attaching of the listener.

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

Query query = db.collection("Properties")
            .orderBy("postTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo("city", city)
            .whereEqualTo("type", type)
if (!area.equals("All")) {
    query = query.whereEqualTo("area", area);
}

query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                propertyListPosition.add(document.getId());
                PropertyFetchObject pfo = document.toObject(PropertyFetchObject.class);

                objects.add(new PropertyListObject(pfo.getPrice(), pfo.getName(), pfo.getArea(), pfo.getSize(), getTime(pfo.getPostTime()), pfo.getCity()));
            }

            PropertiesListAdapter propertyAdapter = new PropertiesListAdapter(PropertyAds.this, objects);
            adsListView.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(PropertyAds.this, "error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it right ?

Yes. As per [the official Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), this is the right way to do it, because you are only making "equalTo" comparisons. The doc gives as an example :

```
citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CO").where("name", "==", "Denver")
```

However, you should read the section about compound queries if you were to make queries with ranges, because then, it would not be the right way to perform it.